# How to delete most recently mail sent in python?

Tags: python, imaplib

Using python and `imaplib`, how can I delete the most recently sent mail?
I have this:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
mail.login('MYEMAIL@hotmail.com', 'MYPASS')
mail.select('Sent')
mail.search(None, "ALL") # Returns ('OK', ['1 2 ... N'])
# doubt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. After get sent mailbox access I was needing to found a message with `fetch()` function and then delete the email message with `expunge()` function. From [imaplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html):

> `IMAP4.expunge()`
>
> Permanently remove deleted items from selected
>   mailbox. Generates an `EXPUNGE` response for each deleted message.
>   Returned data contains a list of `EXPUNGE` message numbers in order
>   received.

My code:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
mail.login('MYEMAIL@hotmail.com', 'MYPASS')
mail.select('Sent')

typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
control = 0
tam = len(data[0].split())
while control < tam:
    typ, data = mail.fetch(tam - control, '(RFC822)')
    if str(data).find(msg['Subject']) and str(data).find(msg['To']) != -1:
        print "Msg found! ", control + 1, "most recently message!"
        mail.store(str(tam - control), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
        mail.expunge()
        break
    control = control + 1

mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) method to open the appropriate folder with read and write permissions. If you do not want to mark your messages as seen, you need to use the examine method.

The sort command is available, but it is not guaranteed to be supported by the IMAP server. For example, Gmail does not support the SORT command.

To try the sort command, you would replace `M.search(None, 'ALL')` with `M.sort(search_critera, 'UTF-8', 'ALL')`

Then search_criteria would be a string like:

```
search_criteria = 'DATE' #Ascending, most recent email last
search_criteria = 'REVERSE DATE' #Descending, most recent email first
search_criteria = '[REVERSE] sort-key' #format for sorting
```

According to [RFC5256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256%20RFC5256) these are valid sort-key's:

```
"ARRIVAL" / "CC" / "DATE" / "FROM" / "SIZE" / "SUBJECT" / "TO"
```

Comment: All I need is to get access to sent mailbox and then delete the most recently message.

Comment: Ok, please see my comment

Comment: Yes, thanks @hd1. Now I know to get access to sent mailbox. But how to delete the most recently message?

Comment: Just have the search_criteria as 'Date', as in the example in my answer and delete the first one.